Meaning of a a phrase, “Not a one of us will not spend an hour or so making merit in a temple before the day is out.”
I am reading, Vulture Peak by John Burdett and came across this sentence on the second page… when the author is introducing a crime scene… and wonder what this means…


"Not one of us will not" = "all of us will".

Please don't post images like that because not everyone can see to read them.

As the references to Buddha, joss, and Farang show, this is not an American culture, but an Asian one.  (Dr. Supatra's name also contributes to this effect.)  External evidence, namely the blurb, indicate that it's Thailand.
The references to "bad luck" and "bad joss" show, the Thai culture is one that believes bad luck is a definite thing that can be inferred from definite signs, and that can act as a miasma, inflicting itself on those who come into range.
Furthermore, the culture also, apparently, holds that you can offset such bad joss by going to a temple and doing deeds worthy of merit there.

Oh, thank you...
